# Why is tableview's setSelected(_:animated:) and setHighlighted(_:animated:) method called on init/load?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Can someone explain to me why the methods [`setSelected(_:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623255-setselected)
 and [`setHighlighted(_:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623280-sethighlighted) are called when a TableView is initialized/loaded?

I would have assumed the methods are ONLY called when I actually highlight/select a cell...

I tested this in a TableViewController with three dynamic, custom cells, where I simply print out some text in the method calls:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    print("setSelected()")
}

override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    print("setHighlighted()")
}
```

Console output:

```
setSelected()
setHighlighted()
setSelected()
setHighlighted()
setSelected()
setHighlighted()
```

Comment: Background information on how I noticed this: I am using a label in my cell with a backgroundColor set to UIColor.darkGray. When I click on a cell, the background of that cell vanishes and when returning to the cell it takes a little until the background shows up again. I am trying to figure out where to set the backgroundColor so that it will not vanish on selecting a cell. I am not sure if both, setSelected() and setHighlighted() are necessary and would like to reduce unnecessary code in those methods. It seems that only setting it in setHighlighted() works, but I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setSelected(_:animated:)` and `setHighlighted(_:animated:)` are called every time when a cell in the TableView is initiated. Because the `setSelected` method is used to set the `isSelected` property when a cell is selected or not. By default every cell is selected `false`. To set selected = false, this method is called.

`setHighlighted` is called every time a cell is initiated. Because every cell is initiated with the `isHighLighted` property is set to `false`. To set this value this method is called by default. Whether you set true or false manually or not.

Answer (score 0):

As per the discussion for method in the documentation:

Parameters:

**selected:**

true to set the cell as selected, false to set it as unselected. The default is false.

**animated:**

true to animate the transition between selected states, false to make the transition immediate.

So in unselected case that during the loading state, it will be false. If you want to perform any action in case of selection ONLY, add a check for if selected to avoid repetition.